# Simple SQL Query in wordpress

Tags: mysql

I want to write a single SQL Query wordpress table wp_options With field name as option_value

For table  wp_options field, option_value, where i want to get user_id and its all associated images

```
Ex. user_id:1 - image 55052a098c146.jpg, imagename.jpg
Ex. user_id:2 - image 55052a098c146.jpg, imagename.jpg
```

In option_value fields here are the  records like the following

```
a: 767: {
    i: 0;a: 8: {
        s: 7: "user_id";s: 1: "1";s: 10: "media_name";s: 17: "550504eb10347.jpg";s: 18: "media_display_name";s: 19: "about_play_img1.jpg";s: 10: "media_type";s: 5: "photo";s: 9: "media_url";s: 95: "example.com/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/550504eb10347.jpg";s: 10: "media_path";s: 111: "/home/content/30/7469030/html/1hotdesign/theplayexperience/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/550504eb10347.jpg";s: 14: "thumbnail_path";s: 105: "example.com/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/thumbnail/550504eb10347.jpg";s: 8: "media_id";i: 0;
    }i: 1;a: 8: {
        s: 7: "user_id";s: 1: "1";s: 10: "media_name";s: 17: "55052a098c146.jpg";s: 18: "media_display_name";s: 22: "Ashleymarie 199 Bw.jpg";s: 10: "media_type";s: 5: "photo";s: 9: "media_url";s: 95: "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/55052a098c146.jpg";s: 10: "media_path";s: 111: "/home/content/30/7469030/html/1hotdesign/theplayexperience/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/55052a098c146.jpg";s: 14: "thumbnail_path";s: 105: "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/userpro/1/media/thumbnail/55052a098c146.jpg";s: 8: "media_id";i: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your query and where are you stuck. Just one question, why aren't you using the build in functions in Wordpress.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Is there any wordpress built in function to display the user_id and images? Sorry, i am newbie to wordpress. Why cant i achieve this in SQL query?